# Blazor validation over a MongoDB Datamodel

Tags: mongodb, validation, blazor, datamodel

I try to link my MongoDB class model to my Blazor page component. I tried to keep all the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute to an interface and let the 'real' class with the Bson decoration apart as:

```
public interface ITestIt
{
    int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Material cost is required")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
    string MyName { get; set; }
}

public class TestIt : ITestIt
{
    [BsonId]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }

}
```

And include it in my page as:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm Model=@testIt OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value=testIt.MyName class="form-control" id="Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => testIt.MyName" Description="Salut" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</EditForm>



@code{

    private ITestIt testIt;
    private bool IsDone = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (IsDone) return;

        testIt = new TestIt();
        IsDone = true;
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }
```

But it don't work, what is the best way to separate the both without having to decorate all my data model with the DataAnnotations tags and not having to copy one by one each property one by one to and other object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Blazor reflects over data annotations of interfaces, only the properties of the implementing object.

I keep my validations in a separate project completely. To do this I use FluentValidation.

You can write a component that accepts an `EditContext` as a cascading parameter, hook into the events where it requests validation, and execute the FluentValidation code.

Or you can use a pre-made library such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterLeslieMorris.Blazor.FluentValidation/

Comment: I saw this one many in my researches. I will take a look. My other approach was by using serialization cloning on two different class with the same structure. But we have to keep updated two data models. This is a design flaw of validation to integrate the rules into the the class instead of the UI inputs...

Comment: Does the asp.net validation look for data annotations on interfaces?

Comment: All the tests I did, the answer is NO... Only in the primary class...

Comment: I tested the one you suggested as: PeterLeslieMorris and I found another one : https://github.com/ryanelian/FluentValidation.Blazor
Who is pretty simple and work like a charm to...

Comment: And I found the https://fluentvalidation.net/ who is more complete.